# tiff images into 1 d array

Tags: python, typeerror, glob

```
import numpy as asarray
dengue_files_A = asarray('dengue_files')
dengue_files_A
```

output:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I am pretty new to python programming. Using the above code, I am trying to produce 1 D arrays from each image. 'dengue_files' has 600 images. I have used glob 2 to read the folder. However, the result of the above code is not in favorable. What could I do to resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: Did you mean `from numpy import asarray`? Otherwise `asarray` is actually an alias for `numpy` which is a module that you are trying to call which is not possible (as error states)

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych - yes. But it says syntax error. Thanks.

Comment: As @YevhenKuzmovych said , you should try this : `from numpy import asarray
dengue_files_A = asarray('dengue_files')
dengue_files_A`

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych - Ok thanks. Will try that

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych - Thank you so much. It worked. However, the output is - array('dengue_files', dtype='<U12'). Not printing out arrays.

Comment: If you have further questions, please create a new question here with what is wrong with your code and what is the expected output

Comment: OK. Thanks. So I know for the fact that                                                                          ``` from numpy import asarray 
dengue_files_A = asarray('dengue_files') 
dengue_files_A```                                                                                                          
 has produced the arrays. However, when I print( dengue_files_A) it throws a output - "array('dengue_files', dtype='<U12'). I do not see the numbers in the output. what is the problem here? Thank you

Comment: What numbers do you expect? You are just creating an array from a string